# Implementing cucumber tags into a testng.xml suite to run selenium drivers in parallel.

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber, testng

Currently using maven to run selenium tests in the testNg framework.
I am specifying the cucumber runner files in a testng.xml suite and running 4 suites one for each browser instance. Below is an example of that testng.xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Test - Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">
    <test name="Online Firefox">
     <parameter name="driver.name" value="firefoxDriver" /> 
    <classes>
        <class name="com.Online.runner.Test1_RunnerTest"/>
        <class name="com.Online.runner.Test2_RunnerTest"/>
        <class name="com.Online.runner.Test2_RunnerTest"/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

I have given tags to each runner file in cucumber options.
I am interested to see if there is a way to specify in the testng.xml file to run all runner classes with specific cucumber tags instead of naming each class runner file individually? So that if I wanted run all regression tests or all sanity tests it would be easy.  Also if there are any constraints of doing it this way? I cant seem to find anyway of doing this any help would be appreciated. Thanks